# Openvino inference engine on c++ with visual studio

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, openvino, inference-engine

I'm trying to use inferenceegine on c++ by runnung the samples test. every things is ok building samples is running with out any error or warnings. but when im trying to run binary files like object_detection_sample_ssd.exe or run main for this sample by using visual studio. its show to this error Application was unable to start correctly what i can do please do u have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not having the dependency binaries like opencv_*.dll in the same folder as your binary. Also InferenceEngine binaries needs to be present in the folder from where your binary is expected to run. Please use DependencyWalker to identify the load dependency and copy the needed binary.

Comment: thanks for asking, I fixed a part of the poblem not its working on release mode but not in debug mode, what do u think?

Comment: I used dependecy walker but there is a file i can not found it VCRUNTIME140_D.dll

Comment: You have VC 2015 dependency.And by the looks of it you should have the debug version of VC runtime on your machine. Can you share the screenshot of the dependency walker.

Answer (score 0):

copy "\inference_engine\lib\intel64\Release\plugins.xml" to project dir, then replace Core core to Core core(plugins.xml)